# Connected App access token is generated but is immediately invalid

Tags: rest-api, accesstoken

I have a connected app which used to work. I generated an access token and was able to use that access token to retrieve other data.

However when I went back to the app after a few months of not developing it the whole process no longer works.

I am using the web server flow according to this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5&language=en_US). I am exchanging my code for an access token and receive the payload with an access token and refresh token. However as soon as I start to use my access token I get a 401 Unauthorized error with the message "Session expired or invalid".

One thing that I saw on the Enable OAuth Settings of the connected app was the "Token valid for 0 Hours" value. However I can see no way of changing this. Am I missing something here?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thank you SaiPraveen Kakkirala for your information about Postman and setting the Follow Authorization Header setting. This helped in Postman. Ultimately, I want to get this working in .NET. I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28671822/1919177) about redirects stripping out the headers and when I examine my code I can see that I am supplying a URL:

```
https://{my-sandbox-domain}.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Campaign/7013L000000BS9vQAG
```

When the unauthorized response comes back it shows that the response request uri was

```
https://{my-sandbox-domain}.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Campaign/7013L000000BS9vQAG
```

Now I am developing this and testing on a sandbox but this redirect is new. I am just wondering how to handle it. Should I simply include the sandbox in my url? How will this be affected when I move to a product environment?

Comment: Are you testing it on postman?

Comment: Yes, I started with code but switched to Postman and am still not getting it to work.

Comment: Can you check if in post man settings "Follow Authorization header" setting is turned ON. Also check if API is enabled for your profile

Comment: The "Follow Authorization Header" was not turned ON and changing that the access token started to work in Postman. I guess the next question is whether that will work in .NET and if there is an equivalent setting.

Comment: Did you check if it is working in .NET?

Comment: No, it is not working. It used to work but that was before when I also did not need to have the Follow Authorization header switched on in Postman. It feels like something has changed since I last worked on this...

Comment: Can you share the code snippet

Comment: Yes to answer your question with enhanced domain change this is expected. You need to add sandbox to the url

Comment: But if the url is for sandbox then you need to change it for production as well I guess. I production Sandbox is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you used it in Postman. You need to check if "Follow Authorization header" setting is turned On in postman under settings. Also we must have API enabled for the profile.

This is not way related to Token Valid for setting in Connected App